# laravel nested controller with 3 model

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, nested-routes, laravel-controller

is possible to use 3 model in laravel nested controller?

this my route now:

```
...
'supplier' => SupplierController::class,
'supplier.item' => SupplierItemController::class,
...
```

i want to use 3 like this one:

```
...
'supplier' => SupplierController::class,
'supplier.item' => SupplierItemController::class,
'supplier.item.price' => SupplierItemPriceController::class,
...
```

is that possible, or i should use another method for this one. i am worry is i do that i won't work or is not the best way to do it.

thanks

Comment: If the route is unique for all then it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

it can

controller example

```
public function show(Request $request, $supplier_id, $item_id, $id)
{
    // ...
}
```